# Rails memory usage - understanding oink output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, oink

I'm using the oink gem to profile my app's memory usage and i'm getting some strange output i'm not understanding.

My home page loads some apartments using `Apartment.where(visible: true)`

When I run this query in the console `Apartment.where(visible: true).count` I get 8.

But when I load the homepage, which should load the same 8 apartments, my Oink logs say:

```
Instantiation Breakdown: Total: 180 | Apartment: 47 .....
```

Do you have any idea where these extra Apartments could be coming from??

Thanks, Uri